# how can i move to next step of timeline

Tags: javascript, html, css

i created timeline, and first step circle is green, now i want next steps circle to fill when i click on next steps. and previous circle will be unfilled.

at the moment step one is selected, when i will click on step 2 text or step 2 circle, previous circle should be outline and next circle should be filled with green color, how can i achieve that.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mattii/z5de0Ljs/190/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="timeline-wrapper"> 
 <ul class="StepProgress">
        <li class="StepProgress-item is-done">
       
            <div class="bold">Step 1</div>
        </li>
        <li class="StepProgress-item ">
         
            <div class="bold">Step 2</div>
       
        </li>
        <li class="StepProgress-item current">
    
            <div class="bold">Step 3</div>
        </li>
        <li class="StepProgress-item">
    
            <div class="bold">Step 4</div>
        </li>
        <li class="StepProgress-item">
          
            <div class="bold">Step 5</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style> 
.bold{font-weight:bold;}
.time{position:absolute; left:-110px;}
.timeline-wrapper {
padding-left:80px;
min-width: 400px;
font-family: 'Helvetica';
font-size: 14px;
/*border: 1px solid #CCC;*/
}
.StepProgress {
position: relative;
padding-left: 45px;
list-style: none;
}
.StepProgress::before {
display: inline-block;
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 15px;
width: 10px;
height: 100%;
border-left: 2px solid #CCC;
}
.StepProgress-item {
position: relative;
counter-increment: list;
}
.StepProgress-item:not(:last-child) {
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.StepProgress-item::before {
display: inline-block;
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: -30px;
height: 100%;
width: 10px;
}
.StepProgress-item::after {
content: '';
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: -37px;
width: 12px;
height: 12px;
border: 2px solid #CCC;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: #FFF;
}
.StepProgress-item.is-done::after {
/*content: "?";*/
font-size: 10px;
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
border: 2px solid green;
background-color: green;
}
/*.StepProgress-item.current::before { 
border-left: 2px solid green;
}
.StepProgress-item.current::after {
content: counter(list);
padding-top: 1px;
width: 19px;
height: 18px;
top: -4px;
left: -40px;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: center;
color: green;
border: 2px solid green;
background-color: white;
}*/
.StepProgress strong {
display: block;
}
</style>
```

Edit: Added JS from comment

**JS**

```
function myFunction() { 
    var element = document.getElementById("id1");
    element.classList.toggle("is-done");
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty easy JavaScript task.  Have you tried writing the JavaScript for it?

Comment: (I did once see someone do this with no JavaScript at all; that was impressive.  I wouldn't recommend you do it that way, though.)

Comment: can you post a solution with js please;  this is not working;
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.getElementById("id1");
   element.classList.toggle("is-done");
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I added a button for your "next" step and added an event listener to it. You can place this event listener elsewhere to do the same thing as well.

```js
function setSelected(e) {
  const list = document.querySelector(".StepProgress");
  
  Object.values(list.childNodes).forEach((it, i) => {
    if (it.classList instanceof DOMTokenList) {
      if (it.classList.contains("is-done"))
        it.classList.remove("is-done");
    }
    
    if(it === e) {
      it.classList.add("is-done");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
<style>.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.time {
  position: absolute;
  left: -110px;
}

.timeline-wrapper {
  padding-left: 80px;
  min-width: 400px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-size: 14px;
  /*border: 1px solid #CCC;*/
}

.StepProgress {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 45px;
  list-style: none;
}

.StepProgress::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 15px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid #CCC;
}

.StepProgress-item {
  position: relative;
  counter-increment: list;
}

.StepProgress-item:not(:last-child) {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.StepProgress-item::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
}

.StepProgress-item::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -37px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: 2px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.StepProgress-item.is-done::after {
  /*content: "?";*/
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid green;
  background-color: green;
}

.StepProgress strong {
  display: block;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="timeline-wrapper">
  <ul class="StepProgress">
    <li onclick="setSelected(this)" class="StepProgress-item is-done">

      <div class="bold">Step 1</div>
    </li>
    <li onclick="setSelected(this)" class="StepProgress-item current">

      <div class="bold">Step 2</div>

    </li>
    <li onclick="setSelected(this)" class="StepProgress-item">

      <div class="bold">Step 3</div>
    </li>
    <li onclick="setSelected(this)" class="StepProgress-item">

      <div class="bold">Step 4</div>
    </li>
    <li onclick="setSelected(this)" class="StepProgress-item">

      <div class="bold">Step 5</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i don't want button, i want to select by clicking on text or circle, one selected item at a time.

Comment: Sorry, you mean you want to have the user click a circle to mark it as selected?

Comment: yes when user will click on circle or text of any list, that item will be selected only, all other would be unselected.

Comment: I've edited it. Take a look. All I had to do was to make sure that only one element had the class at a time.

Comment: Hi, right now only click on text is working, how can i make green buttons clickable too?